# Ubuntu 20.04 bult-in keyboard stopped working

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, budgie

I have a good old ACER Aspire F15 running Ubuntu 20.04.2 Budgie flavour (no dual boot). The built-in keyboard stopped working out of the blue. Last night it was working perfectly, I suspended it overnight and this morning it doesn’t work.

I have updated, followed instructions online tweaking accessibility issues, reinstalled drivers and it doesn’t work for its life.

It’s the second time it happens. Last time it started working again after a couple of hours but I’d like to fix it or at least know what I can do when it happens.

I don’t have access to external keyboard and I can’t open GRUB.

I’m fairly new to Linux systems so I don’t know what more info I should provide sorry.

Thank you.